# Proving equality of mean between ANOVA with 2 levels and t-test

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing, fisher-information

I want to prove that there is an equality of the ANOVA with 2 levels and t-test. So:

From the t-test we know that:

$$t=\frac{\overline{x}_1-\overline{x}_2}{\sqrt{\frac{S_1^2}{n_1}-\frac{S_1^2}{n_1}}} \sim t(n_1+n_2-2)$$
And we know for a fact that if a statistic is t-distributed => $\mu=0$.

Now for ANOVA with 2 levels we should have a null hypothesis:
$$H_0:\mu_0=\mu_1$$

And I guess from this hypothesis we should get something out but I have no idea.

Can someone please show me a prove that this statement is true ?

Comment: The standard one-factor ANOVA is a generalization of the _pooled_ two sample t test. It should use denominator $s_p\sqrt{1/n_1 + 1/n_2},$ where $s_p^2 = \frac{(n_1-1)S_1^2 +(n_2-1)S_2^2}{n_1+n_2 - 2}.$ Your job is to show that $t^2$ from the t test is the same as $F$ from the ANOVA. It should be clear that the denominators match. To show that the numerators match it helps to introduce $\bar X_{..} = (n_1\bar X_1 + n_2\bar X_2)/(n_1 + n_2).$ // Perhaps start with the balanced case with $n_1=n_2 = n$ and then generalize to the case with possibly different sample sizes.

Comment: I don't quite understand what t^2 is, is it Hotelling's T-squared distribution which has F-distribution ?

Comment: Do I have to proove that : $$t^2=S_p^2=\frac{(\overline{x_{1}}-\overline{x_{2}})^2}{\frac{S_1^2}{n1}+\frac{S_2^2}{n2}}=\frac{(n_{1}-1)^2S_{1}^{2}+(n_{2}-1)^2S_{2}^{2}}{n1+n2-2}$$

Comment: In R statistical software, `qf(.95, 1, 18)` returns 4.413873 and `qt(.975, 18)^2` returns 4.413873. (In R `qf` and `qt` are quantile functions of t and F dist'ns, respectively. If you don't use R, look at F and t tables.) This would apply for the case $n_1 = n_2 = 10.$

Comment: Once again, denominator of t is wrong. Eqn in your last Comment makes _no_ sense. On RHS you need formulas for MS(Factor) and MS(Error). After you prove algebraically that $t^2=F,$ you can note that $t^2 \sim F(1,n_1+n_2−2).$ You don't need to consider the complexities of Hotelling's T-squared dist'n for this. I would try to show you a partial answer, but you have shown nothing of what you have tried or of the notation for ANOVA in your text, so it is difficult you show helpful details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that you have never looked *carefully* at the formulas for
a pooled two-sample t test or for a one-way ANOVA. (And that one purpose
of assigning this problem is to get you to do that.) Below both procedures
are computed in Minitab statistical software. The data are ten 
normal observations in group A and ten in group B. I suggest you look at the formulas
and use them to compute what Minitab has computed. Then I'm guessing
you will understand what you need to do.

**Data.** Fake data were simulated as follows: A ~ NORM(100, 10), B ~ NORM(105, 10).
So $\mu_1  \ne \mu_2$ and $H_0$ is false. However, with population SD $\sigma = 10$ there is not enough information with only $n = 10$ replications in each group to detect that $H_0$ is false.

```
A
    99   103    92   105   103    97    98   113    90   112

B
   109    91   110   103   106   100   101   112   114   110
```

**Pooled (equal pop variances) two-sided two-sample t test.** You should
compute pooled SD $S_p$ and T-value.

```
Two-Sample T-Test and CI: A, B 

Two-sample T for A vs B

    N    Mean  StDev  SE Mean
A  10  101.20   7.60      2.4
B  10  105.60   6.95      2.2

Difference = μ (A) - μ (B)
Estimate for difference:  -4.40
T-Test of difference = 0 (vs ≠): 
    T-Value = -1.35  P-Value = 0.193  DF = 18
Both use Pooled StDev = 7.2801
```

**One-factor ANOVA, two levels of factor.** You should compute 
MS(Factor) and MS(Error). In the ANOVA table below these values are
slightly rounded. Note the relationships of MS(Factor) to
the numerator of the T statistic (above) and MS(Error) to the
denominator of the T statistic. The F statistic is the ratio of
MS(Factor) to MS(Error). Verify that the pooled SD is the square root of
MS(Error). Notice that the P-value is exactly the same here as for the
t test above.

```
One-way ANOVA: A, B 

Method

Null hypothesis         All means are equal
Alternative hypothesis  At least one mean is different

Equal variances were assumed for the analysis.

Factor Information

Factor  Levels  Values
Factor       2  A, B

Analysis of Variance

Source  DF       SS      MS  F-Value  P-Value
Factor   1    96.80   96.80     1.83    0.193
Error   18   954.00   53.00
Total   19  1050.80

Pooled StDev = 7.28011
```

Comment: That's very nice but I have to proove that the means are equal not the $\sigma$

Comment: Of course, the t test and ANOVA are _testing_ whether means are equal. But there is no mathematical proof of that. // Equal variances is an _assumption_ -- both of pooled t test and of standard one-way ANOVA. If you are trying to show equivalence of Welch separate variances t test and of one-way ANOVA without equal variance assumption, then you need to make that clear. If df for t is $n_1 + n_2 - 2$ and denom df for F test with 2 levels of the factor would be the same, then you are dealing with pooled t and standard ANOVA. // Before we can help you, you need to be clearer about the the problem